# How to convert coins into paper money or deposit coins into bank account, without your bank in local?

Tags: united-states, coins

I don't have my banks or their deposit ATMs in a place in NY state, and I don't want to open accounts with the local banks.

How can I convert my little jar of coins into paper money, or deposit them into a bank account, without charges?

Do unaffiliated banks or stores welcome the conversion?

Are there banks that accept cash/coin deposits without me visiting their own branches or deposit ATMs? (I can still visit branches of other banks with which I don't want to open accounts)

Comment: Can I mail my coins somewhere for paper money or deposit, without charges?

Comment: Sending coins or cash through the mail is not recommended.

Comment: Aside from the theft risk, mailing the weight of coins will cost you more than they are worth. So effectively, it's cheaper to throw them in the trash.

Comment: Why keep the coins at the first place? Why mot spend them as they come in?

Answer (score 4):

Ask around your area. Some stores will exchange because it saves them having to go to the bank to stock up on change. Some stores have machines that will convert the coins for a small percentage fee.

Some banks *may* do this exchange for folks who aren't customers, though that's uncommon.

My solution was to open a small account locally specifically as a place to dump my coins into. They'll even run a pile of coins through their counting machine for me, free, so I don't have to make up coin rolls as I did in the past.

Comment: Some coin machines will not charge a fee if you take a gift card for a company, like Amazon, or the store where the machine is located.

Comment: @mkennedy: true; in that case they're basically taking their profit as an advertising fee.

Comment: @keshlam And also taking profit on everyone who loses their card.  The ones I've used explicitly provide *no* replacements.

Answer (score 2):

We have machines in several grocery store chains that will take your coins, sort them, and give you two ways to get your money back:

1. Take a receipt to the check out, where they will pay cash, less a small commission.
2. Take a gift certificate for one of a couple dozen stores, in which case you pay no commission but take the risk of losing the certificate and all the money on it.

I've seen these many places, but, of course, I cannot say for sure if there are any near you.